# Using jquery .on to attach custom plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, handler

Let's say I've defined a custom plugin in a separate js file as follows:

```
;(function($) {
$.fn.AjaxImgUpload = function() {
```

In another file I am able to call that function as such:

```
$('#div').AjaxImgUpload({});
```

No problems there, but I need to immediately remove the function call after it's finished. I have the "after" part set up, but I know I have not appropriately attached the function to be removed in the first place. I am thinking there is some way to use .on and .off to do this, like:

```
$('#div').on(AjaxImgUpload({}));
```

Then

```
$('#div').off(AjaxImgUpload({}));
```

This obviously does not work because the function is not an event handler. Is there some way to make it so?

Comment: Are you wanting your function to be fired on click of the `#div` element? If so, take another look at the [.on documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/) and you'll probably be able to figure it out.

Comment: No, the thing is it is fired from a custom API event.. I just need it attached to the element and then detached. Even so my main question (even if it was on a click event) is how to declare the function as something that can be attached to .on and .off. I did try the documentation but I am not that creative to figure it out!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by you want it "detached"? And what exactly is "it", for that matter? You should describe what it is you're trying to accomplish, not just what code you think you need to use. For example: "When the user clicks some button, I want to fire an event that shows an image, but only on the first click" or "upon receiving the response of an ajax request, I want to display an image". Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will not workout with on and off API .There is better option like :

Make two Plugin methods

1. AjaxImgUpld() to get your functionality done.
2. AjaxOffimg() where you put your code that you needed to apply after AjaxImgupld

So first call AjaxImgUpld and then when you want to off it then simply call AjaxOffimg